# Convert a list of intetegers range (1 to 10) to a list of integers range (1 to 3)

Tags: list, range

I want to be able to get a list with a range of numbers 3 or higher,
and turn it into a list of numbers of range 1 to 3 only.
The code only removes some numbers above 3 and leaves others.
I want all numbers above 3 removed from the list.

```
thelist= [1,8,9,2,3]

for element in thelist:
    if int(element) >= 4:
        thelist.remove(element)
    elif int(element) <= 3:
        continue

print(thelist)   
# prints [1, 9, 2, 3]. Number 8 was removed but not number 9
```

Comment: One simple way: `[x for x in thelist if x in [1,2,3]]`. Also, "a list with a range of numbers 3 or higher" doesn't seem to be your actual requirement.

Comment: Or use filter: `list(filter(lambda x: x >= 1 and x <= 3, thelist))`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the else part, so you can delete it.

But your code is not working because you need to make a copy of the list first, you can [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Solution : add [:] after thelist in the for loop

```
thelist = [1,8,9,2,3]

for element in thelist[:]:
    if int(element) >= 4:
        thelist.remove(element)


print(thelist)
```

Comment: Thanks jarmod and msabic22. That's what I needed.

Comment: Downside is that in addition to being O(n) time, which is unavoidable, this is also O(n) space.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to modify a list while iterating over it is going to result in different behavior than you're expecting.

In your example, if you remove `8`, `9` now slots down into the spot `8` was in, and thus is skipped on the next iteration.

You want instead to create a *new* list containing just the values that meet your criteria. This is a good opportunity to use a list comprehension.

```
thelist = [x for x in thelist if x < 4]
```

Should you wish to check that each element is 1, 2, or 3:

```
thelist = [x for x in thelist if x in {1, 2, 3}]
```